# How to add a new key but not add value to dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have been trying to add a new key to my dictionary in swift which was declared as `Dictionary<BagItem, Array<BagItem>>`. However, I could not achieve this. I have been trying to do it in a method like this:

```
static func AddMainItem(item: BagItem)
{
   self.bag[item] = Array<BagItem>()
}
```

**Note:** I have been trying to add only key not add a value. I have debugged the code and I saw that it always updates previous key with new key.

Thank you for your answers
Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to.  You should just update it with an empty string "" for example.  Assigning nil to a dictionary entry is how you remove a key.  Put this in a playground:

```
var dictionary = [String:String]()
dictionary["test"] = nil
println(dictionary)
// [:]

dictionary["test"] = ""
println(dictionary)
// [test: ]
```

Comment: Assume that I have a mainItem and subItems that belongs to each main item. I have a bag in my project and if user wants to add main item to bag or add subItem to bag, he should be able to do it seperately. In my case, If user wants to add main Item to bag, how can I add mainItem to bag? Note: mainItems are keys and sub items are values in my bag structure. @minnesotaSteve

Comment: If you want to use a dictionary there is no concept of main site and subitem, just key:value pairs.  You can always put zero in for the value if there are none.  If you need more complexity than a dictionary think about a custom class or an arrays which store arrays or tuples.

Comment: It is very interesting. I supposed that it has certainly a way to achieve this :) Thank you for your answer @minnesotaSteve